# Postgresql ubuntu 12.04 not starting

Tags: postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL on ubuntu 12.04, using apt-get install postgresql

Everything worked fine. I made database, inserted data etc.

Then I rebooted my computer, and postgres did not start. There is nothing in /etc/postgresql. service postgresql start / stop /restart do nothing.

pg_lsclusters displays nothing.

What on earth has gone wrong? How do I start postgresql?

Where on earth are the database tables stored?

Comment: Did you create a cluster with pg_createcluster?

Comment: No. I use installed postgresl, then connected to it and created tables/users etc. I have no idea about any cluster.

Comment: That ... doesn't make a ton of sense. What's in `/etc/postgresql`? What about `/var/lib/pgsql` (might be `/var/lib/postgresql/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was harddisk corruption.